# Include an InputStream in Velocity

Tags: java, include, inputstream, velocity

In a Velocity Template Language script, I can use the [`#include`](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/releases/velocity-1.7/user-guide.html#Include) directive to read Velocity macros and script elements from a local file.

I would like to store my Velocity script library in the database instead.

Can I `#include` from a Java `InputStream`, either from a VTL script or from the Java application calling [`org.apache.velocity.app.Velocity#evaluate`](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/releases/velocity-1.7/apidocs/index.html?org/apache/velocity/app/Velocity.html)?

Comment: Any updates on this? I'm dealing with large files and I try to get a grip on the memory footprint of velocity templates...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Velocity 1.5, [`DataSourceResourceLoader`](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/devel/apidocs/org/apache/velocity/runtime/resource/loader/DataSourceResourceLoader.html) allows loading templates from the JDBC DataSource configured in the [Velocity properties](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/releases/velocity-1.7/developer-guide.html#Configuring_Resource_Loaders).

The configured properties file can be as simple as:

```
resource.loader=class, ds
class.resource.loader.class=org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.ClasspathResourceLoader

ds.resource.loader.class=org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.DataSourceResourceLoader
ds.resource.loader.resource.datasource=...
ds.resource.loader.resource.table=...
ds.resource.loader.resource.keycolumn=...
ds.resource.loader.resource.templatecolumn=...
ds.resource.loader.resource.timestampcolumn=...
```